# CSS Child Selectors - Need to target a child element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm fairly new to css selectors, but I have an html structure with child elements that I need to select. I've tried a few methods, but I am having a hard time selecting just the elements I need. To pre-answer: the HTML is added by a third party software, and I can not modify it in any way. This includes adding classes to elements.

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="smith-category-menu">
    <div>
        <div>
            <table></table>
            <div>
                <table></table>
            </div>
            <table></table>
            <div>
                <table></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to be able to select the following:

```
<div class="smith-category-menu">
    <div>
        <div>
            <table SEELCT1></table>
            <div SELECT2>
                <table SELECT3></table>
            </div>
            <table SELECT4></table>
            <div SELECT5>
                <table SELECT6></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried `div.smith-category-menu div div table` and `div.smith-category-menu div div table:first-child` but they are both also selecting strange elements.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does it have to support <IE9 (which impacts CSS3 selectors)? http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
div.smith-category-menu>div>div * {
    border:1px solid #aa0000;
}
```

[**See this demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/y3Jtk/)

Comment: I'm curious, what does the * reference?

Comment: `*` matches all elements. So, this selector is saying, "match all elements that are a child of three divs in succession, where the first has the class `smith-category-menu`."

Comment: Also, `>` means a **direct descendant,** and a **space** means **any descendant, no matter how far down.** So if you had a standard `<table><tr><td>` structure, then `table td {}` would match the `td`, while `table>td {}` would not.

Comment: Man, I wish I would have known this about three weeks ago :) Better late than never. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If that's the exact structure, you can use this selector:

```
div.smith-category-menu > div > div * {
    ...
}
```

or you can edit HTML a little:

```
<div class="smith-category-menu">
    <div>
        <div>
            <table class="old-classes select-me"></table>
            <div class="old-classes select-me">
                <table class="old-classes select-me"></table>
            </div>
            <table class="old-classes select-me"></table>
            <div class="old-classes select-me">
                <table class="old-classes select-me"></table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and use:

```
div.smith-category-menu .select-me {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just a space in your selector, like

```
div table {
    ...
}
```

will select all table elements that are in a div's descendants, not just its direct descendant. Using a ">" instead will select direct descendants only.

```
div > table {
   ...
}
```